# file_save_data doesn't save image

Tags: 7, files

I'm using Drupal 7.56..
I want to upload images from other urls..
I use:

```
$image_original_path = '.. here my original path..';
$my_destination = 'sites/default/files/images/';
$my_new_name = 'my_image.jpg';
$filename = $my_destination.$my_new_name;
$image_object = file_get_contents($image_original_path);
$file = file_save_data($image_object,  $base_url.'/'.$filename, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
```

But the image is not uploaded..
Any idea please?
Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is fixed by

1. going to **admin/config/media/file-system** and save configurations with **temporary folder** = **tmp**
2. check permissions 777 on tmp folder
3. `$filename = 'my_image.jpg';
    $image_object = file_get_contents('...original_image_s_path...');
    $file = file_save_data($image_object, 'public://' . $filename, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);`

This saves my image under sites/default/files

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**
Try with this code:

```
$image_original_path = '.. here my original path..';
$image_object = file_get_contents($image_original_path);
$file = file_save_data($image_object, file_default_scheme().'://'.basename($image_original_path),FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
// Add this code also
if (is_object($file)) { // if you get back a Drupal $file object, everything went as expected so make the status permenant
  $file->status = 1;
  $file = file_save($file);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. But it doesn't work!!

Comment: @sana Please try the updated code.

Comment: Thank you.. But after running I have this error "The website has encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Comment: Please check the code because this code is working fine at my end.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: No not yet. I still looking for this error "The website has encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Comment: what about this error 'The file could not be created.' ? I found it in includes/file.inc line 1963. How can I fix it? Thank you..

Comment: 1. Check the file path
2. Check the Folder Permission.
3. Try to debug code line by line.